# Why php iteration by reference returns a duplicate last record?

Tags: php, iteration

I just spent 2 hours hunting a bug which apparently comes from a foreach iteration with &value. I have a multidimentional array and when a ran this:

```
   foreach($arrayOfJsonMods as &$item){
        //TODO memcached votes
   }
```

and PHP returned an array with the same element count, BUT with a DUPLICATE last record. Is there something i don't understand about this structure?

I ran the code on a different machine, and the result was the same.

Comment: This shouldn't happen, can you provide some example?

Comment: +1 for the courage to post an SO question that just has to be a user-error, but isn't. Easily just spent 2 hours debugging and adding logging and simplifying code until I had no choice but to google php foreach duplicate and got here. Many thanks @vasion.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'll guess that you're **reusing** `&$item` here and that you're stumbling across a behavior which has been reported as bug a thousand times but is the correct behavior of references, which is why the [manual advises](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

> Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

```
foreach($arrayOfJsonMods as &$item)
{
   //TODO memcached votes
}
unset($item);
```

See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29992

Comment: Eight years later and this just saved all my hair from being pulled out after an hour. Thank you.

Comment: Saved me from banging my head on the desk. I still don't understand why is this an expected behaviour of reference and is not a bug. Even though $item still points to the last element of $array after foreach ended, why would doing var_export on $array resulted in duplicate items at the last row? It makes zero sense!