# PHP 5.4 ForEach madness?

Tags: php, foreach, iteration

I'm not sure how to word it.

Take the following example.

```
<?
$arr = array('first','second','third', 'fourth');
foreach ($arr as $k=>&$n) {
    $n = $n;
}
var_dump($arr);
>?
```

returns

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "first"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "second"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "third"
  [3]=>
  &string(6) "fourth"
}
```

That makes total sense, why would anything change? Well, adding a second loop that doesn't even do anything is where I got lost.

```
<?
$arr = array('first','second','third', 'fourth');
foreach ($arr as $k=>&$n) {
    $n = $n;
}
foreach ($arr as $k=>$n) {
;
}
var_dump($arr);
?>
```

returns

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "first"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "second"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "third"
  [3]=>
  &string(5) "third"
}
```

The last value of the array has become the same as the second to last. Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969243/strange-behavior-of-foreach/4969286#4969286

Comment: [Here is a nice description of exactly this effect](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/141-References-and-foreach.html) and why it happens with reference iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're turning `$n` into a reference:

```
foreach ($arr as $k=>&$n) {
                     ^----
```

Once a PHP variable is "referenced" like that, it **STAYS** a reference, so in your next loop:

```
foreach ($arr as $k=>$n) {
```

That `$n` will still be a reference to the **LAST** item you iterated over in the first loop.

Comment: That's a great way to word it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You got the address operator & before $n in the first loop. Removing that will solve the problem.

This problem is explained here:

[Why php iteration by reference returns a duplicate last record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158741/why-php-iteration-by-reference-returns-a-duplicate-last-record)

Comment: @Jhawins What do you mean, that is the exact problem right now. I just ran the code without the & and it works as expected.

Comment: I'm in the middle of something. I don't see how that could be it but I'll read it

Comment: I get it now. That's odd. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A stab in the dark but maybe try resetting the internal pointer of the array using `reset()` ?

http://www.php.net/reset

```
<?
$arr = array('first','second','third', 'fourth');
foreach ($arr as $k=>&$n) {
    $n = $n;
}

reset($arr);
foreach ($arr as $k=>$n) {
;
}

var_dump($arr);
?>
```