# Array of strings - translation

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an array of strings:

```
$items = array ('Silver', 'Black', 'Orange');
```

I would like to use WordPress [_() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) to make strings translation-ready, so I constructed the following and it works:

```
  $items = array( __( 'Silver', 'my-textdomain' ), __( 'Black', 'my-textdomain' ), __( 'Orange', 'my-textdomain' ));
```

How can I avoid repeating text domain or even better, use my first array to create second array?

Comment: You can take domain name as variable and pass variable instead of the text.

Comment: $doamin_name  = 'my-textdomain'; $items = array( __( 'Silver', $doamin_name ), __( 'Black',$doamin_name  ), __( 'Orange', $doamin_name  ));

Comment: My goal is to keep array with colors clean, without text domain constant or variables and preferably without functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
$items = array ('Silver', 'Black', 'Orange');   

foreach ($items as &$item) {
    $item = __( $item, 'my-textdomain' );       
}
unset($item);
```

Comment: I used `$item` later in my code and it caused last 2 elements of array be the same, "Black" in this case. It's solved by line `unset($item);`. This problem is covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158741/why-php-iteration-by-reference-returns-a-duplicate-last-record